# Strava API - How set activity type for Uploaded Activity?

Tags: api, strava

I want to upload my gpx files via Strava API. I read documentation and there is no mention about set Activity type and privacy at Upload endpoint and no API for editing activities.

What can I do?

Comment: After uploading the gpx, you are returned an activity id that you can use to update your activity https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-updateActivityById

Comment: Thanks, it's have type of activity, but not privacy settings

Comment: Yeah, privacy settings are missing, but you can use "hide_from_home" property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit activity type and set the `hide_from_home` flag to true.

The recipe is as following:

1. Upload activity via [Upload Activity (createUpload)](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Uploads-createUpload).
2. Get `activity_id` via [Get Upload (getUploadById)](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Uploads-getUploadById) method. It may take a while to get that ID as the upload needs to be processed by Strava.
3. After you get Activity ID, you can update the activity via [Update Activity (updateActivityById)](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-Activities-updateActivityById) PUT method. There, you can set one of the [UpdatableActivity](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-models-UpdatableActivity). Ones that might be interesting for you are:

   - [`sport_type`](https://developers.strava.com/docs/reference/#api-models-SportType)
   - `hide_from_home`

There is no possibility to update `private` property via the API as for the moment.